# Multiple Javascript Asynchronously Loading in a Page

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadScript(scriptpath) {
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    var ss = document.createElement('script');
    ss.type = 'text/javascript';
    ss.async = true;
    ss.src = scriptpath;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ss, s);
}
loadScript('compressed1.js');
loadScript('compressed2.js');
</script>
```

but i am getting error that SS is not defined can somebody help me with above coding?

Comment: you create a variable called ssa and make a call to just ss later. 
either rename the variable to ss or rename your calls to it as ssa.type and ssa.async etc.

Comment: even after that it doesn't work

Comment: when you say it doesn't work what do you mean? are you getting the same error? is it a new one? check your console for errors and give more information and maybe we can help you. otherwise we're taking shots in the dark

Answer (score 0):

`var ssa`

Keep variable names consistent. It's usually a good idea to give meaningful names like `newScript`

Comment: it doesn't help see what i am missing in above?? The idea behind above script is loading 2-4 java script file asynchronously

Comment: even after that it doesn't work i corrected it and still same error

Comment: can anyone help here?? with the above coding?